vscode debugger wont stop on breakpoints
I'm trying to use the debugger to analyze a C program, but isn't working
this is launch
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": 
    [
        
        {
            "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\programacao-C\\msys2(toolsANDlibrarysForCorC++)\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": 
            [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
}

this is tasks
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\programacao-C\\msys2(toolsANDlibrarysForCorC++)\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g3",
                "-Wall",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

I tried to setup stopAtEntry to True, only this way the program stopped, but I couldn't see which line the debugger stopped and variables or other things, I don't know why this is happening.

Use "ignoreFailures": false so you can tell something goes wrong.
